# Bathroom extractor fan and lights not working

Tags: bathroom

Hello who can help me am in Florida and a storm has been through and now my bathroom lights and extraction fan are not working, I've disconnected my fan and the lights still did not work , I changed the one switch which powers bothe of the units.the breaks do not trip and the rest of the power to my bathroom still works

Comment: Do you have a GFI? Why did you replace a switch and disconnect wires without knowing the fault? What I mean, is more like what led you to believe you should change the switch? Do you have a voltage tester or a meter? Do you have experience with working on electrical? Do you know what breaker powers the fan & light? Is it the same one as the rest of the bathroom? Have you secured the breaker power, made sure the fan/light HOT is off, and gone into the fan looking for water? You have a few things to check before replacing parts or turning the power back on. (for fire safety reasons)

Comment: I know which breaker controls my fan and lights, the hair dryer and shaving socket is still working. So it is the the power for the light and fan which has gone. I unplugged the fan and the lights still did not work. I did isolate the breaker in question before I removed anything. Also it is just one switch which controls both fan and lights. I removed a switch from the other bath room to rule the switch out. I do not have a voltage tester.

Comment: Without having a voltage tester, and not knowing the basics of home wiring, calling in some help is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't answer whether you have a GFI, this is important information. While the outlets should be controlled by a GFI, we don't know what kind of setup you have or if ANYTHING ELSE is not working besides just the fan and light.

...and while you may know what breaker controls the fan+light, we do not. I asked about what else the breaker controls to determine if there are other things the breaker that controls the fan+light controls and if they are working. If they are (or are not) working, it also then matters where in the circuit these things are.

You said a bad storm caused the light to stop working. For all we know, you have a roof leak or a bad vent flap and water came in and shorted the circuit out.  You would need to address the bigger issue of stopping the leak, to avoid a fire or shock issue as well as ensuring your structure doesn't rot from mold or water damage before even turning power back on to test things.

Swapping a switch with no reason to do it as a "guess" or "just to see" is what is called shot-gunning or guesswork. It also demonstrates it is safest if you call an electrician.

Honestly, changing things as a guess often introduces more issues if mistakes are made, it also confuses matters more, and makes it much harder for people to solve. (For example, now you have two switches that have had wires removed and reconnected, bent, and bent again... are they tight? did they stress crack? did you re-splice it? what condition are any wire nuts in? are any of those connections now compromised? these questions are now important in two switch boxes instead of one).

AC power has the potential to kill and it should be done with this in mind at all times.  An electrician will have this issue sorted out quickly and will also be able to tell you very quickly if the storm had anything to do with it, and if you need to call anyone else in for other repairs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, there is no leaks in the loft my circuit board is clearly marked up and the breaker controls every thing in my second bedroom. Do understand what you are saying. I am getting someone to take a look at it today

Comment: What did you find out??